# \n and \t method won't combine with variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

Can't we use \t and \n in variables?

```
var1 = " Ryan "

print (\tvar1.strip() + \nvar1.lstrip() +  \nvar1.rstrip())
```

I get an error:

```
syntax error : unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: If you're asking whether tab and newline characters can be used in Python identifiers, the answer is no.

Comment: @Stardust Relevant documentation: [Identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

Comment: This explains the error message: [Explicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining): *"Two or more physical lines may be joined into logical lines using backslash characters ... A backslash is illegal elsewhere on a line outside a string literal."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to treat them as regular characters and concatenate them properly with other strings:

```py
print('\t' + var1.strip() + '\n' + var1.lstrip() + '\n' + var1.rstrip())
```

*(edit from [ShadowRanger's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330193/n-and-t-method-wont-combine-with-variable/57334794?noredirect=1#comment101159264_57334794))*:
If you are on Python 3.6+, you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) instead of the `+` operator:

```py
print(f"\t{var1.strip()}\n{var1.lstrip()}\n{var1.rstrip()}")
```

If you can't use f-strings yet, you can use the regular [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

```py
print("\t{}\n{}\n{}".format(var1.strip(), var1.lstrip(), var1.rstrip()))
```

You can also include them directly in literal strings:

```py
str1 = "\tabc\ndef"
```

Comment: Or use `str.format` or f-strings to let you use them with names in the middle, e.g. the f-string solution: `print(f'\t{var1.strip()}\n{var1.lstrip()}\n{var1.rstrip()}')`